# System.typeload exception thrown when instantiating object of class SmsNamedValuesDictionary

Tags: .net, sccm-2007

A System.typeload exception is being  thrown when instantiating object of class SmsNamedValuesDictionary.All the assemblies that have to be referred have been referenced correctly.I have to pass this object to WQLConnectionNManager class to connect to SCCM console.

Answer (score 0):

The dll reference was the problem